# CenterCrop scale type not working on image loaded with Picasso

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-imageview, picasso

I'm trying to load a photo (downloaded via a url) into an imageview and have it span the entire width of its parent view, which is a row in a listview.

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/property_row_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/search_list_item_height"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Setting the scaleType directly on the ImageView seems to do nothing. I know the height of each row, so I'm measuring the width and then using that to call Picasso's Resize and CenterCrop methods like so:

```
var height = Convert.ToInt32 (ApplicationContext.Activity.Resources.GetDimension (Resource.Dimension.search_list_item_height));
viewHolder.Photo.Measure (0, height);
var width = viewHolder.Photo.MeasuredWidth;
var url = property.ThumbnailPhotoUrl.Replace ("/thumbnails/", "/{0}/{1}/".WithFormat (width, height));
viewHolder.Photo.SetUrlBitmapWithCenterCrop (url, width, height, 
                    loadingResourceId: Resource.Drawable.property_row_background,
                    errorResourceId: Resource.Drawable.image_not_available);

public static void SetUrlBitmapWithCenterCrop (this ImageView imageView, string url,
            int width, int height, int? loadingResourceId = null, int? errorResourceId = null) {
            Picasso.With (imageView.Context)
               .Load (url)
               .Placeholder (loadingResourceId ?? 0)
               .Error (errorResourceId ?? 0)
               .Resize (width, height)
               .CenterCrop ()
               .Tag (imageView.Context)
               .Into (imageView);
        }
```

Unfortunately, the centerCrop scaleType isn't being applied, I see big white borders to the left and right of each photo. Any idea what I'm missing? Note that I've tried the Fit method as well, no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try using both fit and centerinside

```
  Picasso.with(getContext()).load(path).fit().centerInside().into(iv);
```